# TextImage_On option bit for user-defined filegroup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created 2 tables like this

```
Create Table t1
(
     [c1] varchar(max),
     [c2] int
) on [Primary]

Create Table t2
(
     [c1] varchar(max),
     [c2] int
) on [Primary] TextImage_on [myfilegroup]
```

and also inserted into them the same data but am unable to find how different they are. I'd like to know which bit or flag value is set on the second table to tell SQL Server that one or more of its columns is being stored on `[myfilegroup]` and the rest on the default storage.

Any helpful idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prior to SQL Server 2005 there was a special IAM chain dedicated to LOB pages, starting with 2005 there are allocation units that contain this information.
You can read more on this here: [Inside the Storage Engine: IAM pages, IAM chains, and allocation units](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-iam-pages-iam-chains-and-allocation-units/)

You can use some script like this:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) as obj_name, 
       --fg.data_space_id,
       fg.name,
       --fg.type_desc,
       au.*
from sys.partitions p inner join sys.allocation_units au 
        on au.container_id = p.hobt_id 
     inner join sys.filegroups fg 
        on fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id 
where fg.name = 'myfilegroup'
      -- and p.object_id = object_id('t2');
```

to see what page types are belonging to your filegroup (this code shows you aggregated information per object per page type)

and you can get the detailed (per page) information joinig this code to sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations() (of course passing in db_id() and object_id() to limit the rows returned)